# RegEx sentence must contains Consonants and Vowels

Tags: regex

I don't really understand about RegEx, and I want to make sentence/whole string have to have consonant and vowel letters, and there can't be numbers, symbols and so on. Can you help me? thank you.

For example

```
eat: match
I eat a sandwich: match
1 eat a s4ndwich: not match
yyy: not match
aaa: not match
```

This is what I tried

```
([aiueo][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])\w+
```

Comment: What is the context for this question? Is this data being input by the user and sent via an HTML form? Or is it a search query?

Comment: What do you mean by `I eat a sandwich: match` Do you want to match individual words or the whole string?

Comment: A sentence/whole string, sorry. @Thefourthbird

Comment: You could use 2 lookahead assertions https://regex101.com/r/vsGjZy/1 `^(?=.*[aiueo])(?=.*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])[a-zA-Z ]+$`

Comment: Woah It worked, thanks! Don't you want to make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\w` could also match a digit or an underscore. As you only want to match chars a-z, you could use a character class and add a space `[a-zA-Z ]`

To make sure the string contains at least 1 consonant and 1 vowel, you could use 2 lookahead assertions so the pattern can not match an empty string when the space is added to the character class.

You could make use of the principle of [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) first matching any char that is not what is listed, then match one of the listed.

```
^(?=[^aiueo\n]*[aiueo])(?=[^b-df-hj-np-tv-z\n]*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FoSkn1/1)

Comment: Very nice. Though this does have the usal problem of when 'y' is used as the single vowel in a word. Why is Y so sly! Stymy thing!  See - http://www.wordsthatbeginwith.com/scrabble/y_is_only_vowel_words